# Sort values for stacked frame

Tags: pandas, sorting, stack, pivot

I would like to have a little help from your side.
Following issue: I do have two big excel files which I stacked and merged via concat. The resulting file consists of two indices (MultiIndex) and two numerical columns. I calculated the difference for between the two numerical column. Now I need to sort the values based for the difference column, without changing the order of the 0 level inde, i.e.

```
ID   Description                                                                 Difference
4533754105 BESCHRIFTUNG - TINTENSTRAHLDRUCK                                             0.000  
           DOSIEREN (1.SEITE)                                                           0.000  
           DOSIEREN (2.SEITE)                                                           0.000  
           EINSETZEN 1. SEITE MIT ROBOTER                                               0.000  
           EINSETZEN 2. SEITE MIT ROBOTER                                               0.000  
           EINSPRÜHEN GIEßSCHALE MIT TRENNMITTEL                                        0.000  
           EINSTREICHEN DICHTUNG MIT SCHMIERMITTEL                                     -0.235  
           ENTFORMEN PATRONE MIT LUFTDÜSE UND PRÜFE                                    -0.140  
           FADENWICKEL MIT MITTELROHR                                                  -0.149  
           FALTEN PAPIER UND ABSCHNEIDEN AUTO.                                          0.000  
           KLEBEN BALG                                                                 -0.159  
           VERPACKEN NACH VERPACKUNGSDATEI                                              0.000  
           ZUSCHNEIDEN FADENÜBERSTAND                                                  -0.056  
1444517S01 1. SEITE - EINSETZEN FILTERTEIL                                             -0.408  
           2. SEITE- NEHMEN FILTERTEIL KOMPL. MIT                                       0.000  
           BESCHRIFTUNG - TINTENSTRAHL                                                  0.000  
           EINRAFFEN BALG UND SICHERN MIT RAFFGUMMI                                    -0.372  
           EINSPRÜHEN GIEßSCHALE MIT TRENNMITTEL                                        0.000  
           ENTFORMEN PATRONE UND PRÜFEN                                                -0.270  
           FALTEN PAPIER UND ABSCHNEIDEN AUTO.                                          0.000  
           KLEBEN BALG                                                                 -0.364  
           VERPACKEN NACH VERPACKUNGSDATEI                                             -0.480
```

Above is the raw data after stacking, merging and calculating the difference. ID and description are here the indices. As you can see differences are not ordered

What I need is to order the value for the difference column, i.e.

```
4533754105 EINSTREICHEN DICHTUNG MIT SCHMIERMITTEL                                     -0.235  
           KLEBEN BALG                                                                 -0.159  
           FADENWICKEL MIT MITTELROHR                                                  -0.149  
           ENTFORMEN PATRONE MIT LUFTDÜSE UND PRÜFE                                    -0.140  
           ZUSCHNEIDEN FADENÜBERSTAND                                                  -0.056  
           BESCHRIFTUNG - TINTENSTRAHLDRUCK                                             0.000  
           DOSIEREN (1.SEITE)                                                           0.000  
           DOSIEREN (2.SEITE)                                                           0.000  
           EINSETZEN 1. SEITE MIT ROBOTER                                               0.000  
           EINSETZEN 2. SEITE MIT ROBOTER                                               0.000  
           EINSPRÜHEN GIEßSCHALE MIT TRENNMITTEL                                        0.000  
           FALTEN PAPIER UND ABSCHNEIDEN AUTO.                                          0.000  
           VERPACKEN NACH VERPACKUNGSDATEI                                              0.000
```

If I apply the sort_values function it messes up the indices, i.e. different indices are in the same group. This is because sort values, sorts the values of the entire column, but as I need to sort_values within the same group in this case within the ID group.

I unstacked the frame, but due to size of the file it is really getting messy.

Any kind of idea

Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 2):

From [pandas 0.23+](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.23.0.html#sorting-by-a-combination-of-columns-and-index-levels) is possible sorting by columns nad levels together:

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Difference'])    
print (df)

                                                     Difference
ID         Description                                         
1444517S01 VERPACKEN NACH VERPACKUNGSDATEI               -0.480
           1. SEITE - EINSETZEN FILTERTEIL               -0.408
           EINRAFFEN BALG UND SICHERN MIT RAFFGUMMI      -0.372
           KLEBEN BALG                                   -0.364
           ENTFORMEN PATRONE UND PRÜFEN                  -0.270
           2. SEITE- NEHMEN FILTERTEIL KOMPL. MIT         0.000
           BESCHRIFTUNG - TINTENSTRAHL                    0.000
           EINSPRÜHEN GIEßSCHALE MIT TRENNMITTEL          0.000
           FALTEN PAPIER UND ABSCHNEIDEN AUTO.            0.000
4533754105 EINSTREICHEN DICHTUNG MIT SCHMIERMITTEL       -0.235
           KLEBEN BALG                                   -0.159
           FADENWICKEL MIT MITTELROHR                    -0.149
           ENTFORMEN PATRONE MIT LUFTDÜSE UND PRÜFE      -0.140
           ZUSCHNEIDEN FADENÜBERSTAND                    -0.056
           BESCHRIFTUNG - TINTENSTRAHLDRUCK               0.000
           DOSIEREN (1.SEITE)                             0.000
           DOSIEREN (2.SEITE)                             0.000
           EINSETZEN 1. SEITE MIT ROBOTER                 0.000
           EINSETZEN 2. SEITE MIT ROBOTER                 0.000
           EINSPRÜHEN GIEßSCHALE MIT TRENNMITTEL          0.000
           FALTEN PAPIER UND ABSCHNEIDEN AUTO.            0.000
           VERPACKEN NACH VERPACKUNGSDATEI                0.000
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['ID','Difference'], ascending=[False, True])    
print (df1)
                                                     Difference
ID         Description                                         
4533754105 EINSTREICHEN DICHTUNG MIT SCHMIERMITTEL       -0.235
           KLEBEN BALG                                   -0.159
           FADENWICKEL MIT MITTELROHR                    -0.149
           ENTFORMEN PATRONE MIT LUFTDÜSE UND PRÜFE      -0.140
           ZUSCHNEIDEN FADENÜBERSTAND                    -0.056
           BESCHRIFTUNG - TINTENSTRAHLDRUCK               0.000
           DOSIEREN (1.SEITE)                             0.000
           DOSIEREN (2.SEITE)                             0.000
           EINSETZEN 1. SEITE MIT ROBOTER                 0.000
           EINSETZEN 2. SEITE MIT ROBOTER                 0.000
           EINSPRÜHEN GIEßSCHALE MIT TRENNMITTEL          0.000
           FALTEN PAPIER UND ABSCHNEIDEN AUTO.            0.000
           VERPACKEN NACH VERPACKUNGSDATEI                0.000
1444517S01 VERPACKEN NACH VERPACKUNGSDATEI               -0.480
           1. SEITE - EINSETZEN FILTERTEIL               -0.408
           EINRAFFEN BALG UND SICHERN MIT RAFFGUMMI      -0.372
           KLEBEN BALG                                   -0.364
           ENTFORMEN PATRONE UND PRÜFEN                  -0.270
           2. SEITE- NEHMEN FILTERTEIL KOMPL. MIT         0.000
           BESCHRIFTUNG - TINTENSTRAHL                    0.000
           EINSPRÜHEN GIEßSCHALE MIT TRENNMITTEL          0.000
           FALTEN PAPIER UND ABSCHNEIDEN AUTO.            0.000
```

Comment: Not working, since "ID" is in index. If I applay your advice I get "KeyError: ID".

Comment: My version is '0.20.1'.

OK let me do it with a newer version and I will let you know :)